# Mod_Rewrite for URL with multiple variables | .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I develop an e-shop site with products so for this proposal i made a product page for each of products with Mod_Rewrite for URL with the code above in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ ./product.php?name=$1 [L]
```

So when user clicks on the link www.example.com/Nike-Air goes to Nike-Air shoes page and etc.

What i would like to do is to add one parameter more in the url, let's say size

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ ./product.php?name=$1&size=$2 [L]
```

but this parameter to not append in the url, still to displays www.example.com/Nike-Air
and also to be able to get the size data from $_GET method.

Is it possible?

Any ideas guys?

Comment: `size` must appear somewhere in your URL so that your internal handper `product.php` can get it

Comment: What does the pipe character signify in your URL?